# How does ClientID and ClientSecret work in a NodeJS API with OAuth2 authentication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to implement OAuth2 authentication in a REST NodeJS application with Express + Passport. My REST NodeJS application will be an API/service to be offered to a mobile application TEST1 (another different app which I'm developing for Android).

In OAuth2 there are a ClientID and a ClientSecret. For example, in Facebook, Google, etc, APIs/services, we can access a kind of "control panel" and create these ClientID and ClientSecret parameters to insert into the mobile application that will access Google or Facebook API/services. In my NodeJS app I have no control panel...

**QUESTION 1**: How do I create the ClientID and ClientSecret that will be inserted into my Android? (those parameters will be sent to my NodeJS app for access it)

**QUESTION 2**: The ClientID and ClientSecret parameters will be always the same on all Android devices running my app TEST1 while accessing NodeJS service/REST API? Or should each device have its own ClientID and ClientSecret?

Comment: have you read any [documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/oauth2-api/)

Comment: Yes, I read. But I didn't understand what I need to do to answer my own questions 1 and 2.

Comment: right ... I'd only repeat what's documented, so I'm out